# Filling the gap between 2 paths on a canvas

Tags: android

Im developing an android app with the help of dlib, i have a code that with the help of the 68 face landmarks i draw a path for the outer part of the lips and another one for the inner path of the lips is there any way that with 2 different paths i can fill the gap in between them?
i've seen methods like, fill the outer one and fill the inside one with white so it looks like you're only painting the outside part but i cant do that since im painting it over the an image and i just want to color the lips, is there any way to accomplish this?

This is the code i used to paint the lips:

```
for (final VisionDetRet ret : results) {
    // Draw landmark
    int x = 0;
    ArrayList<android.graphics.Point> landmarks = ret.getFaceLandmarks();
    int ppX = 0, ppY = 0;
    Paint mFaceLandmardkPaint = new Paint();
    mFaceLandmardkPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mFaceLandmardkPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    mFaceLandmardkPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    Path pth = new Path();
    pth.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
    Path pth2 = new Path();
    pth2.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);

    for (android.graphics.Point point : landmarks) {

        if (x >= 48 && x <= 60) {
            int pointX = (int) (point.x);
            int pointY = (int) (point.y);

            if (x != 48) {
                //canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, ppX, ppY, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
                pth.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            } else {
                pth.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            }
            ppX = pointX;
            ppY = pointY;
            //canvas.drawCircle(pointX, pointY, 1, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
            } else if (x > 60) {
                pth.close();
            }
            if (x >= 61) {
                int pointX = (int) (point.x);
                int pointY = (int) (point.y);
            if (x != 61) {
                //canvas.drawLine(pointX, pointY, ppX, ppY, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
                pth2.lineTo(pointX, pointY);
            } else {
                pth2.moveTo(pointX, pointY);
            }
            ppX = pointX;
            ppY = pointY;
            //canvas.drawCircle(pointX, pointY, 1, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
        }
        x++;
    }
   pth2.close();
   Paint red = new Paint();
   red.setColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
   red.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   c.drawPath(pth2, mFaceLandmardkPaint);
   c.drawPath(pth, red);
}
```

This code generates a full painted mouth.
Is there any way to accomplish this with native canvas, paint and paths?

Comment: What do you mean by 'native' canvas paint and paths? Those are the typical drawing methods for Android unless you want to use OpenGL

Comment: Yeah, i just want to avoid answers that use OpenGL or any other kind of external Libraries.

Comment: What API's in your posted example are you trying to avoid? Those are standard calls.

Comment: Ah no, what i mean is that i cant accomplish what i want with this piece of code.
I Have 2 paths one in the inner part of the lips and one in the outer, i want to paint the gap between these 2 paths, that piece of code paints the whole mouth instead, i want an answer that avoids using external libraries to just paint the gap.

Comment: if you have two paths you can make several `Path.Op` logical operations on them

Comment: Oh, ill check Path.Op out, i didnt knew it existed.

Comment: but actually you could also try `Path#addPath(Path src)` - with `Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD` it should work as well - its my theory since i never tried that

Comment: Ill check that out and report how it turned out

Comment: Well, better late than never, some urgent stuff happened but, i checked and the addPath did solve my issue, thanks @pskink
if you want to post it as an answer please go ahead.